# List all commits for a specific directory and its children?

Tags: git, version-control, terminal

I'm trying to list all commits for a specific directory and all of its children.

I've had a look through some git documentation (https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-log) regarding the `git log` command, but the closest I can seem to get is somehing like:

```
git log --grep="nameOfPlugin"
```

But, whilst this is somewhat helpful, it's not reliable enough in this circumstance.

I can also seem to find ways of listing all commits for a specific file, e.g.

```
git log -- foo.py bar.py
```

But this isn't helpful unless I iterate through all directories/subdirectories, then compile a list of file paths + names, pass this to git log, then concatenate all duplicate commits (this seems a bit mental to me).

Is there some simple way of doing this that I'm missing?

**To give some background**

I'm looking for all internal modifications made to a CMS plugin before updating it.

I know this is bad practise etc. etc. but it's sometimes unavoidable (especially when hooks aren't implemented well).

We have kept some brief internal documentation regarding custom modifications made to the plugin, but I don't really trust them. I know we probably could have kept better internal documentation but this circumstance is surely a good reason VCS like git are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more tinkering, this turned out to be as easy as:

```
git log --stat path/to/directory/in-question
```

The `stat` parameter gives a list of which files where modified in each commit, the `p` parameter would also list all changes (which may be useful in some cases).

Should have read the man page properly!